# converting JSON object in spring MVC

Tags: javascript, json, web-services, rest, spring-mvc

in the example below i have one method `sendJsonResponce` method which is nothing but the putting string values to Map and we are returning that map from `createChildSalesPosition` method to our webpage.

we are using `Spring` `MVC` here, as i have gone through some websites saying that you need to change the object to `JSON` type when you want to send a `JSON` response but in my project i find this which is sending `JSON` response without any type conversion in `JSON`.

since the guy who had developed the application is no more available i got stuck here.

```
@RequestMapping(value="createChildSalesPositions.json",produces="application/json")
            @ResponseBody
            public Map<String,String> createChildSalesPositions(@RequestParam("tId") Integer templateId,@RequestParam("prnSalesPosId") Long prnSalesPosId,@RequestParam("prnSalesHierId") Long prnSalesHierId,
                    HttpServletRequest request,@ModelAttribute("ALIGNMENTINFO") AlignmentInfo alignmentInfo,@ModelAttribute("USERSESSION") UserDetails userDetails)throws BusinessException, IOException{       
                try{


                return sendJosnResponse(crId);                  
            }
            }catch(Exception e){            
                return sendErrorResponse(e);            
            }
        }   




private Map<String,String> sendJosnResponse(long crId) throws IOException{
        Map<String,String> tosend  =new HashMap<String,String>();
        tosend.put("code", "200");
        tosend.put("message", "CR "+crId+" has been generated successfully.");  
        tosend.put("crId", String.valueOf(crId));
        return tosend;
    }
```

Comment: You can add the jackson library to your classpath

Comment: as per my understanding its getting converted to JSON response automatically due to written produces="application/json on the top of method @ArunPJohny

Comment: Yes, but somebody should help Spring to do that, it is done via MessageConverters, http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-enable

Comment: okay,so in order to use that produces="application/json i need to add that library... right ?? @ArunPJohny

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the spring framework how to convert the java object to json. The spring framework uses `HttpMessageConverter` to do that, to convert the java object to json spring can use the jackson libraray.

To enable this support you can either use the `@EnableWebMvc` annotation or `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` xml configuration and add the jackson library to your classpath.